# How do I find/replace � (unicode replacement character) in ColdFusion?

Tags: unicode, coldfusion

What CFML will replace � with another character of my choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
replaceNoCase(text, chr(65533), " ", "ALL")
```

http://www.ghidinelli.com/2006/07/25/invalid-unicode-character-65533

Comment: Is it necessary to use the NoCase variant?

Comment: Maybe not, you can try it out.